Spring boot 3 in Payara 6
I need some help to know how to deploy a Spring Boot 3 application on a Payara 6 server, I created the WEB-INF folder and put the web.xml and beans.xml under the Jakarta 10 definitions, but it tells me that it is unable to load the Jakarta EntityManager Bean, does anyone know how to solve this? I can't get any information.

It is better to provide simple scripts to describe your issue.

If you want to load EntityManager by Spring, do not use a persistence.xml. And then I think JPA EntityManager will work in Spring as expected.
If you want to use the container(eg. Wildlfy, Paraya, etc.) built-in EntityManager service and create a shared EntityManger bean.
I have some examples using mixed Spring and Jakarta EE, but I used Wildfly as the runtime server. Check JPA config.
